# how to make visual studio project portable? (where to set includes/libs/preprocessor definitions etc.)

Tags: visual-studio-2012

In Visual Studio 2012 I have native C++ project. There are a lot of settings in "Properties" page of this project:

- Additional Include Directories
- Preprocessor definitions
- Additional Library Dependencies
- etc.

Later I need to migrate to Linux, and of course I need this settings too. Obviosly Visual Studio project can not be used in Linux

Can you suggest another, platform-independent, mechanism of declaring Additional Include Directories/Preprocessor definitions/Additional Library Dependencies etc. so I can migrate to Linux easier?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[cmake](http://www.cmake.org) might fit your needs: it's a cross platform build system that allows to configure your project in a compiler-independent way. For Windows, it is then able to generate Visual Studio Project files based on that configuration.

Comment: am I correct that cmake is "ant for c++"? how easily I can switch between eclipse and command-line build?

Comment: @javapowered cmake works on a level above that: you configure all dependencies etc in a CMakeLists.txt file and run cmake on that to generate, e.g., a Visual Studio solution (on Windows), an Eclipse project file or a regular Makefile ("ant for c++"). cmake also keeps them up-to-date so that you can fully configure the project in the CMakeLists.txt file, what enables you to switch compiler and/or OS at any time.

Comment: thanks Niko it sounds too complicated for me, what if I only want to support Linux and do not need extra level of abstraction?

Comment: Give it a try, it's actually not complicated at all once you've got used to it.

Comment: Are there other options? I have simple command line C project in VS. How can I just send a ZIP file to a friend which will allow him to fully reproduce what I have? Thank You.